# Python regex capture group split issue

Tags: python, regex

Trying to understand a regex example in python and here is my code

```
line='bar asdfgh klmn,     foo'
print(re.split(r'(;|,|\s)\s*',line))
#output is ['bar', ' ', 'asdfgh', ' ', 'klmn', ',', 'foo']
```

In the output it shows the strings and the seperators, the last seperetor is a comma with five spaces not just a comma

If the seperator was just a comma, shouldn't the output be like this?

```
#output ['bar', ' ', 'asdfgh', ' ', 'klmn', ',', '     foo']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) splits the provided string by the pattern, returning what you capture in parentheses as part of the results.

In this case your regular expression matches "a semi-colon, a comma, or a whitespace character (which is captured and returned) followed by 0 or more whitespace characters (which are discarded)". As a result the whitespace after the comma in your example is consumed when the comma is matched and is not present in your output.

Answer (score 3):

If capturing groups are used in the regex, then `re.split` includes the contents of the captured groups. However, it still uses the whole match as the separator, which leads to the behavior you observed. If you want `"".join(split_results)` to be equal to the original string, you'll need to capture the entire separator (and use non-capturing parens where you've got parens now: `r'((?:;|,|\s)\s*)'`).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend splitting on the following pattern:

```
\s*[,;]?\s+
```

This says to split on optional whitespace and either comma or semicolon separator, followed by one or more spaces.

```
line='bar asdfgh klmn,     foo'
print(re.split(r'\s*[,;]?\s+', line))

['bar', 'asdfgh', 'klmn', 'foo']
```

The problem with your current pattern is that it leaves space optional, if a comma/semicolon separator be present.  This is resulting in spaces appearing as matched terms.